# How to find the element with an attribute and change the attribute value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="x" src="X.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
```

After dropping the image how can i change the attribute value `draggable="true"` to `draggable="false"` by finding the available elements with attribute `draggable="true"` inside the function `drop()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements having `draggable set to true`. using `setAttribute` set `draggable to false`

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
  var elem = document.querySelector('.className');
  elem.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('draggable', false))
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="x" src="X.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
```

Comment: This works. One more think is i want to find with query selector inside a class only. How can i do that?

Comment: or in one go as I posted: `document.querySelectorAll('.classname[draggable="true"]')`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]').forEach(elem =>
  elem.setAttribute("draggable",false)
);
```

Older JS

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]');
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
  elems[i].setAttribute("draggable",false);
}
```

Using a class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.someClass[draggable="true"]')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `forEach(function(elem) {`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]');
```

in order to find elements with a certain attribute.

Note that this works only for HTML attributes, for classes you shall use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classname[draggable="true"]')
```